# Understanding the Usage of /* in IBM Transformation Extender (ITX) Mapping Rules

Tags: wtx

I've been working with IBM Transformation Extender (ITX) recently, and I've noticed that in some of the mapping rules, the /* sequence is used. I'm aware that in programming, /* often indicates the start of a multiline comment, but I'm uncertain about its purpose within ITX mapping rules. Does /* have any specific significance or behavior in ITX, or is it just a convention for adding comments?

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
<MapRule rulenumber="5">
    <objectset>Orders:sequence2:OrderImportRequest:global:MSE</objectset>
    <objectrule>=F_Order (Payload:JSON:DNA)
    /*
    =F_Order (Extract (Payload:JSON:DNA
        ,Member(State:Payload:JSON:DNA
            ,{&quot;PLANNED&quot;,&quot;CANCELLED&quot;})
        )
    )
    */
</objectrule>
</MapRule>
```

I'd like to understand if /* serves any specific purpose in ITX mapping rules or if it's simply a convention for adding comments for documentation. Any insights or clarification would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This syntax has no special meaning in rules, and is just for the purpose of entering comments, to be excluded by the compiler.